# least square mean

Tags: mean, least-squares, multiple-comparisons, adjustment

[Here](http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/lsmeans2.htm) I read that when comparing groups with different characteristics (age, percentage of males, body mass index) means should be corrected for such imbalances. These corrected means are called adjusted means or least squares means. Adjusted means are predicted values from a multiple regression equation (hence, the name least squares means).

Could you please tell me how to calculate these adjusted means (in matlab if possible)?
Please consider that I have 4 groups and I should adjust for more than 2 factors (age, gender, bmi, MMRC).

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you should just do an ANOVA

Comment: @bdeonovic I can't...data are not normally distributed within the groups.

Comment: This sounds like a time for a regression model. Would you be able to do a nonparametric regression that doesn’t assume normality?